# Как запустить несколько корутин в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Начал работать с одним проектом. Создал корутины. Они берут значения с сервера и записывают их в параметры объекта.
В чем проблема: мне нужно вызывать их для нескольких объектов, и когда я прописываю их по очереди, происходит так, что одна корутина не успела взять значения с сервера, а вторая уже вызвалась, либо наоборот. Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы корутины вызывались только после того, как завершится предыдущая.

У кого какие варианты? Мне достаточно теории. Код не обязательно.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я не в курсе что за корутины и не работаю с юнити, потому просто как догадка - нет ли возможности создать большую корутину, а другие корутины вызывать внутри нее в нужном вам порядке?

Comment: Слишком много кода получится. Корутины наподобие асинхронных методов. В корутинах можно возвращать результат, который требует времени для завершения. То есть, ждать. Например, до тех пор, пока не получится подключиться к интернету (для примера).

Comment: Ну, составить большой асинхронный метод из маленьких вообще не проблема :)

Comment: Проблема решена с помощью операторов switch, case. Я добавил порядковый номер к корутинам,и они вызываются по очереди при увеличении индекса.

Comment: switch-case - топорное решение, чем вам не нравится хранить корутины в массиве и вызывать их по тем же индексам?

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция yield return внутри тела IEnumerator является эдакой точкой передачи управления.

Грубо говоря если вы делаете yield return new WaitForSecond(2) - корутина передаёт управление внутрь этого класса и ждёт пока он не закончит свою работу, после чего возвращается и продолжает работу дальше.

Аналогичным образом можно передавать управление и другим корутинам

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(FirstRoutine());
}

IEnumerator FirstRoutine()
{
    yield return null;
    print("Пропущен кадр");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    print("Прошла секунда");

    yield return StartCoroutine(SecondRoutine());
    print("Прошло две секунды");
}

IEnumerator SecondRoutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

В вашем случае будет одна корутина, например, `LoadRoutine()`, которая последовательно передаёт управление в другие корутины, которые получают и применяют необходимые данные.

Comment: Я понимаю, но на данный момент такое решение не подходит. А так, спасибо.

Comment: @General2001, а почему не подходит?